# Junit5 with ant

Tags: ant, junit5

[image: Errors during ant command]

I am new in ant and junit5. I went through several examples ant/junit4. But I did not find a normal example with a pair of ant with junit5. With a pair of ant with junit4 everything works fine. I downloaded the files from the official site of the junit5 https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/ (For Ant, check out the junit5-jupiter-starter-ant project.), but even they give an error at the very beginning(screen attached) I will try to fix them one by one, but I don't think that official repo committed with errors. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Or maybe gurus suggest some other simple sample with ant/junit5.

Thank you in advance.

I try to run the original sources from https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples and expected to at least compile them. But I get plenty of errors.

Comment: Since the examples in junit5-samples are continuously being built and tested, I’d assume that you did something wrong when you couldn’t get them to compile.

Comment: Thank you @johanneslink. I also think that I did something wrong. But what should I do if I just clone clean repo and try to run ant command which is works on my side for other projects with build.xml files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this post has 2 questions:

- errors on the screenshot
- ant+juni5 integration in general

1. To reproduce the exact issues one should have the same environment, which is at least the OS, Java version & Ant version. The example itself seems to be using the Junit5 ConsoleLauncher, which is one of the way to run the tests. Looking at the errors it looks like the issue is in the project itself, because if it cannot find the 'symbol' @Test then the Junit(5?) is simply not present on the classpath. Maybe this can be a hint to the author to trty to dig a bit more into the issue, particularly looking into the dependencies (jars) included.
2. Now going back to how to run Junit5 test with Ant, I can recall the "JUnitLauncher" that apache suggests: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitlauncher.html . Note that you should be attentive on the dependencies here as well, there are number of Jars to be included (opentest4j, junit-platform-xyz). Note that this also depends on the installation of Ant in the environment, so for example if you get a `NoClassDefFound` for `JUnitLauncher`, this can be solved by using the 'up-to-date' version of Ant: https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi . In case of Linux you can place these Jars in home/your_username/.ant/lib directory, where it will be automatically picked up.